# Progress OpenEdge Developer Studio “Dark Mode”

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I just started as a Progress OpenEdge developer and I was wondering if it was possible to change the Developer Studio IDE to resemble that of “Dark Mode” on other IDEs. In other words, can you change the background color of the IDE or is there some solution out there already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern versions of Progress Developer Studio (at least OpenEdge 12.2 and 12.3) support Dark Mode in Windows -> Preferences and then General -> Appearance

[image: Preferences Dialog]

You may have to fine-tune the editor colors in General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the _UIB-CODE-BLOCK generated lines have darker background by modifying the 'Read-Only code background color' this can be accessed in Menu: Windows -> Preferences, then navigate tree view to Progress OpenEdge -> AppBuilder -> Editor (it is further down the list, so I kept missing it)

Or simply remove the 'Make AppBuilder generated cod read-only' and code background should be the same color

[image]